# Total demand for two different prices, where market shares are determinened by logit model

Tags: exponential-function, estimation

The setting is simple, i.e. formula for demand of service/product is linear
$$
  d = \alpha - \beta p
$$
where $ \alpha $ is maximum demand, $ \beta $ is some coefficient, and $ p $ is price. There are two firms, with different prices $p_1$ and $ p_2 $, and the prices are fixed, so there is no competition. The fraction of total demand for the first firm is captured by the logit rule
$$
  f_1 = \frac{e^{-\gamma p_1}}{e^{-\gamma p_1} + e^{-\gamma p_2}}
$$ 
where $ \gamma $ is some sensitivity coefficient. Similar for the other price/firm.

**Question**: how can I compute total demand in this setting?

EDIT: I asked this question on QF forum, but without luck. I had an answer, but it turns out that it is wrong. Now I have another answer:
$$
  d(p_1, p_2) = W - \beta\cdot\min\{p_1, p_2\}
$$
It seems OK, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If demand really is linear, then to total demand should be the sum of each firm demand.  That doesn't match the logit rule, so it looks like something is missing in the specification. One guess might be that $e^{-\gamma p_1} +e^{-\gamma p_2} gives total demand, since it is the denominator of the share.

Comment: Demand is linear if there is only one firm on the market. But if the two firms are in the market, i.e. there are two prices, then I don't know what is the formula for total demant. That is what I am looking for. I only know that when there are two firms/prices, that market share between them is calculated by logit rule.

Comment: If you've given all the information in the problem, then it appears that $e^{-\gamma p_1}+ e^{-\gamma p_2} is a consistent solution that obeys the downward sloping properties of demand curves.